# Don't allow me to select "invalid flag" when a post, having an already handled flag using a default reason, is then flagged with a custom reason

Tags: feature-request, flags

When handling flags on Stack Overflow, I noticed the following flag.

> [image: screenshot]

As you note, the flag reason is written with a different text color, and the flag is dated 7 months ago. At first I didn't notice that, and I invalidated the flag. Only after, I noticed the different text color and trying to understand what the reason could be, noticed the date. At that, I remembered I was said that it means the post has been flagged with a custom reason I cannot see as I am not a moderator, and what I am shown is a flag using a default reason that has been already handled.

Since I cannot see why the post has been flagged, I should not be called to judge the correctness of the flag. That means one of two things:

- I should not see that post between the flagged posts
- I should not be able to select "invalid flag" since I don't see what the flag says

Probably the first option is excessive; it could be I find another reason to flag the post, or I flag that post with the same (or similar) reason used by who flagged with a custom reason. If the second option is not possible, then I am fine with the first one.